# How to Fix Qt Custom Terminal Prompt Messy Codes Problem

Tags: linux, bash, qt, qt4

I made a terminal by binding bash with *QProcess*:

```
// c++ in Qt4.8.7 on CentOS7
process_ptr->start("bash -i", QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Append);
// With the "-i" option, interactive bash is able to display the *prompt*
```

Commands are entered through *QCmdLine*, fed to *QProcess*, and the output is printed to *QPlainTextEdit*

And I have merged the standard output channel with the standard error channel:

```
process_ptr->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
```

The problem is: the command prompt(set by PS1) in *QPlainTextEdit*, which is used to display stdout or stderr, is messy.

**Specifically, the content printed in *QPlainTextEdit* is as follows:**

```
^[]0;eng@hostname:~^G[eng@hostname 15:36:41 #17 ~]$
ls

Desktop
Documents
Downloads
Music
Pictures
Public
Templates
Videos
^[]0;eng@hostname:~^G[eng@hostname 16:05:12 #18 ~]$
echo $PS1
[\u@\H \t #\# \W]\$
^[]0;eng@hostname:~^G[eng@hostname 16:05:35 #19 ~]$

^[]0;eng@hostname:~^G[eng@hostname 16:05:36 #19 ~]$
```

And I have set PS1 as

```
PS1="[\u@\H \t #\# \W]\$ "
```

It looks like the second half of the command prompt `[eng@hostname 15:36:41 #17 ~]$` is what I set up correctly via PS1.

**Now I don't know how to get rid of the first half** `^[]0;eng@hostname:~^G`, where `^[` denotes the ASCII control character "ESC" and `^G` denotes the ASCII control character "BEL"

I've researched the concept of *tty* for this issue: my practice of binding a fixed bash via *QProcess* bypasses line discipline and pty, in other words input and output content is *written/read* directly to the bash process without going through line discipline and pty(Here's the link, it might be useful: [tty/pty](https://dev.to/napicella/linux-terminals-tty-pty-and-shell-192e))

At the moment I'm not sure which module I should look at to locate the root cause of the problem: standard output/error channel redirection, the underlying principles of bash, *QPlainTextEdit* in Qt, etc.

Thank you very much for your valuable thoughts or solutions!

Comment: Are you going to take care of that terminal for a longer time? I ask because Qt4 is actually in the process of being phased out (since 2018/19 of I remember correctly!), and thus I'm a bit surprised you're using it to develop something new!

Comment: @MarcusMüller
Custom terminal do need to be used for a long time.
The reason for using version 4.8.7 is that newly developed applications need to work with existing Qt applications (4.8.7): inter-process communication via QUdpSocket or QDBus*.
I understand your surprise, but there are still a lot of people using Qt4 for development (it's very robust)~q(≧▽≦q)~

Comment: I get that, though UDP and dbus bindings do exist for Qt5 and Qt6.

Comment: I suspect your problem has to do with terminal control ANSI escape sequences, and we're only seeing the printable characters. Did you have a look at a hexdump of the data to see whether it might contain unprintable characters?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Extremely grateful!
I'll study the ANSI escape sequences and debug it right away.
So much to learn! o(≧口≦)o

Comment: Have a look through startup files (including `.profile`/`.bash_profile` since it's a login shell) to see whether anything modifies `PS1` there.  And make sure you have `TERM=dumb` set in the shell's environment, so it's not causing programs to fetch the wrong terminal escapes.

Comment: It might be useful to start your shell with `-x` to help diagnose what's happening in the startup scripts, then grep the result for `PS1=`

Comment: @TobySpeight
Thank you o(*^▽^*)┛
Have tried setting the `TERM` variable to `dumb`, `linux` or others;
`PS1` is no problem, always `[\u@\H \t #\# \W]\$ `;
The `-x` or `-v` options are only for bash scripts;
My own feeling is that there is some mechanism for prefixing prompt with ASCII control characters;
My current approach is to abandon the customized terminal approach and use the `export` function to get around the garbled code by launching `xterm` or `xfce4-terminal` or `gnome-terminal` through a bash sub-process

Comment: You say "_`-x` or `-v` options are only for bash scripts_".  Which is mistaken on two counts: the question is tagged [tag:bash] and these options are standard ones, recognised by all POSIX-compliant shells.  So there's no problem using them here for the investigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably something in your `.profile` (or `.bash_profile` - or even, wrongly, `.bashrc`) that modifies your `PS1`.  For example, on my system, `bash -ix -c true 2>&1 | grep PS1= | cat -v` reveals these:

```bash
+ PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
++ PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
+ PS1='\[^[[1m^[[32m\]\u@\h\[^[[39;49m\]:\[^[[34m\]\w\[^[(B^[[m\]\$ '
+ PS1='\[\033]0;\u@\h: \w\007\]\[^[[1m^[[32m\]\u@\h\[^[[39;49m\]:\[^[[34m\]\w\[^[(B^[[m\]\$ '
```

A likely underlying cause is that you have `TERM` set in the environment from the shell which executed the Qt program.  Well-behaved startup scripts will use `tput` or similar to find the correct escape sequences, so exporting `TERM=dumb` to your shell process should give a plain prompt.  We can demo this using `TERM=dumb bash -ix -c true 2>&1 | grep PS1= | cat -v`:

```bash
+ PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
++ PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
+ PS1='\[\]\u@\h\[\]:\[\]\w\[\]\$ '
```

If I remember correctly, the `^[]0;`…`^G` sequence is an **xterm** control code to set the window title.

Comment: Appreciate it very much! o(*^＠^*)o

Following your tips, the problem has been solved:
Method: `PROMPT_COMMAND=""`
[(PROMPT_COMMAND)](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Xterm-Title-4.html).

Specifically, I have observed the `PROMPT_COMMAND` related scripts/functions, which have `case` statements to determine if the `TERM` variable is `xterm` or not.

One oddity is that the `PROMPT_COMMAND` related content still prints even if I set `TERM` to `dumb`; 
this can only be resolved by manually clearing the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable.

Thanks again!

Comment: Some programs think they know best, and completely ignore `TERM`.  It looks like you have found one; I recommend submitting a bug report to get it fixed (but in the meantime, simply not using it is a reasonable short-term workaround).